# Using mobileconfig to access advertiser identifier on mobile safari

Tags: javascript, ios, udid

I'm trying to get the IFA of an iOS device but having a hard time figuring out how to go about that. I know with mobile config profiles you can access the UDID but I need the advertiser identifier if possible. 
As a bonus, I'm also hoping to get info on the advertiser setting (if they disabled tracking).

Anyone know a way to get this?
Thanks

Comment: Any luck with this so far ? I am looking for answer since last couple of months and no luck :(

Comment: I have not had any luck doing it this way, I had to take another approach. :(